# Install doctrine-fixtures

Tags: php, git, symfony, doctrine

I would like install doctrine-fixtures with file deps. I added this lines to my file deps:

```
[doctrine-fixtures]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
```

and if i run

```
php bin/vendors install
```

i have error:

```
>Installing/Updating  doctrine-fixtures
fatal: Not a git repository <or any of parent directories>: .git
fatal: Not a git repository <or any of parent directories>: .git
fatal: Not a git repository <or any of parent directories>: .git
```

I try also `php bin/vendors install --reinstall` and `git=https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git` but it did not help.

Comment: Strange... try adding `target=/doctrine-fixtures`, maybe...

Comment: ? Are you trying to communicate?

Comment: all others are install OK, also DoctrineFixturesBundle. This problem is only with doctrine-fixtures

Comment: the main difference is it doesn't have a target. This is why I asked you to add one. But I still don't understand your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sound crazy but if that is your last line in deps file, try to put new line after it. I had similar problem, no EOL and bundle failed to install.